# web service not returning json as expected

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

I have the following webservice, which, when testing via the asp.net "view in browser" does retrieve data which it shows in xml on the browser

Here is the webservice

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Text

<ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="BATLDataRetrieval")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
Inherits Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
   <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetOhlcvData(ByVal symbol As String) As List(Of StockPricesDTO)
    Dim tempList As New List(Of StockPricesDTO)
    Dim stockData As New ArrayList()

    Using ctx As New BATLEntities()
        Dim symid As Long = (From sym In ctx.last60dayssymbols Where symbol = sym.symbol Select sym.id).FirstOrDefault()
        Dim data = (From ohlcv In ctx.last60daysdata
                    Where ohlcv.lastSixty_symbolId = symid
                    Select ohlcv).ToList()

        For Each dataDay In data
            Dim tempSp As New StockPricesDTO
            tempSp.QuoteDate = DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(dataDay.date)
            tempSp.Open = dataDay.open
            tempSp.High = dataDay.high
            tempSp.Low = dataDay.low
            tempSp.LastSale = dataDay.last
            tempSp.Volume = dataDay.volume
            tempList.Add(tempSp)
        Next
        Return tempList
    End Using
End Function
```

I use this service to retrieve stockdata from our db to use as follows
and I need it to return data in json in this format

```
[[1162512000000,79.36,79.53,77.79,78.29,15426335],
[1162771200000,78.95,80.06,78.43,79.71,15525782],
[1162857600000,80.45,81.00,80.13,80.51,18788494]....]
```

The actual json returned per fiddler is

```
{"d":   [{"__type":"StockPricesDTO","QuoteDate":1383282000000,"Open":1031.79,"High":1036.00,"Low":1025.10,"LastSale":1027.04,"Volume":1283300},{"__type":"StockPricesDTO","QuoteDate":1383195600000,"Open":1028.93,"High":1041.52,"Low":1023.97,"LastSale":1030.58,"Volume":1616400},{"__type":"StockPricesDTO","QuoteDate":1383109200000,"Open":1037.43,"High":1037.51,"Low":1026.00,"LastSale":1030.42,"Volume":1324100},
```

The javascript code is

```
 $(function () {
        var symbol = "GOOG";  //will replace with <a> tag click value
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/GetOhlcvData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{symbol: "' + symbol + '"}',
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
                showChart(data.d);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        function showChart(chartData) {
            $('#chartContainer').highcharts('StockChart', {
                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1
                },
                title: {
                    text: symbol + ' Stock Price'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: symbol,
                    data: chartData,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }]
            });
        }
    });
```

The alert(data.d) produces [object Object] instead of the actual data in json. This is my first attempt at creating a service that returns json so please excuse my ignorance if this is a simple task.

Comment: if you debug with chrome tools or firebug, what does the data within `data` look like?

Comment: in fiddler it shows the first item in each array of data as _type=StockPricesDTO.... is that whats causing the issue? see edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to replace

```
data: '{symbol: "' + symbol + '"}',
```

with

```
data: {symbol: symbol},
```

You will see more (than when using alert()) if you

- output to console `console.log(data)`
- don't use MSIE, but Chrome, Firefox, ... and their Web-Developer utitilies
- look in the network tab of Chrome Webinspector/Firefox Firebug and analyze request and response

In the console (or the debugger) you can inspect what is returned by your server and tell us, if you don't come along with it.

Comment: 0: Object
High: 1036
LastSale: 1027.04
Low: 1025.1
Open: 1031.79
QuoteDate: 1383282000000
Volume: 1283300
__type: "StockPricesDTO"   is what chrome console is showing as return

Comment: If highchart really needs the data in form `[[n,n,n],[n,n,n],...]` you either have to transform the data server-side or client-side. I'd do it client-side. If you can count on ES5 this is just a matter of some `Array.map` calls. Do you need help on that? What about my answer - was it helpful?

Comment: Answer accepted, as it lead me down the road which ended up with me using an arraylist and returning the data as such